# Can you compare meta-analytic correlations?

Tags: correlation, meta-analysis

I have performed a meta-analysis on correlations and now have meta-analytic correlations. This has resulted in 5 meta-analytic correlations $(A, B, C, D, E)$.

I was wondering is there a way to compare these correlations statistically. I.e. is correlation $A$ larger than $B$.

I know I can do this with the `r.test` function in R normally inputting a sample size, correlation $A$, correlation $B$, and the correlation between $A$ and $B$.

However, I was wondering if this is appropriate for meta-analytical coefficients.

I ask this because the sample size I would be putting into the formula is the combined sample of the studies in my meta-analysis. Which I presume is what the SE's are based of off.

So I was wondering

A) How do you compare meta-analytic correlations with each other statistically

B) Can it be done by the `r.test` function

Comment: Are these from separate batches of studies?

Comment: So it is a meta-analysis on two studies.

Study A has 501 participants and has 5 variables correlating to one outcome
Study B has 287 participants and has 5 variables correlating to one outcome

Comment: Did you figure out the answer to this question? I am very curious to know.